# No have audio/video in freeswitch

Tags: webrtc, freeswitch

I'm have no audio and video when using WebRTC client (SIP, JsSIP, ...etc) + FreeSWITCH Version 1.5.14 (64bit) + Chrome Version 46.0.2490.71 (64-bit).

Log from caller

```
INVITE sip:1001@10.10.77.168 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/WSS hvr4pagq2h9f.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK3062994
Max-Forwards: 70
To: <sip:1001@10.10.77.168>
From: <sip:1000@10.10.77.168>;tag=mhl4eq6vao
Call-ID: 70fsn4l5nr0fkaouc6fm
CSeq: 5808 INVITE
Contact: <sip:bas2g8qe@hvr4pagq2h9f.invalid;transport=ws;ob>
Allow: ACK,CANCEL,BYE,OPTIONS,INFO,NOTIFY
Content-Type: application/sdp
Supported: outbound
User-Agent: SIP.js/0.7.2
Content-Length: 3631

v=0
o=- 8910623958632335387 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
a=group:BUNDLE audio video
a=msid-semantic: WMS dchcZgUwyg28FURu8N1orjN1XU09wjZq8k4B
m=audio 31713 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 9 0 8 106 105 13 126
c=IN IP4 118.69.35.22
a=rtcp:31745 IN IP4 118.69.35.22
a=candidate:2620772478 1 udp 2122260223 10.10.77.200 52225 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:2620772478 2 udp 2122260222 10.10.77.200 56486 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:3535154318 1 tcp 1518280447 10.10.77.200 0 typ host tcptype active generation 0
a=candidate:3535154318 2 tcp 1518280446 10.10.77.200 0 typ host tcptype active generation 0
a=candidate:1780853162 1 udp 1686052607 118.69.35.22 31713 typ srflx raddr 10.10.77.200 rport 52225 generation 0
a=candidate:1780853162 2 udp 1686052606 118.69.35.22 31745 typ srflx raddr 10.10.77.200 rport 56486 generation 0
a=ice-ufrag:jwwczpAehfzwcMgI
a=ice-pwd:fzk6kXPAkSW5ITfMPRXcj64T
a=fingerprint:sha-256 7F:E3:9A:28:1B:30:9B:83:A7:15:D3:ED:A0:34:3C:15:6B:A8:2D:AD:76:0F:AC:AB:10:62:E0:AB:80:5E:78:F2
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:audio
a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=sendrecv
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
a=fmtp:111 minptime=10; useinbandfec=1
a=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000
a=rtpmap:104 ISAC/32000
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:106 CN/32000
a=rtpmap:105 CN/16000
a=rtpmap:13 CN/8000
a=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000
a=maxptime:60
a=ssrc:4132922782 cname:nsTu7lEciv/5dY7Z
a=ssrc:4132922782 msid:dchcZgUwyg28FURu8N1orjN1XU09wjZq8k4B db705e69-7099-45d5-a3b9-731010988ed4
a=ssrc:4132922782 mslabel:dchcZgUwyg28FURu8N1orjN1XU09wjZq8k4B
a=ssrc:4132922782 label:db705e69-7099-45d5-a3b9-731010988ed4
m=video 31777 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 100 116 117 96
c=IN IP4 118.69.35.22
a=rtcp:31809 IN IP4 118.69.35.22
a=candidate:2620772478 1 udp 2122260223 10.10.77.200 43305 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:2620772478 2 udp 2122260222 10.10.77.200 37514 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:3535154318 1 tcp 1518280447 10.10.77.200 0 typ host tcptype active generation 0
a=candidate:3535154318 2 tcp 1518280446 10.10.77.200 0 typ host tcptype active generation 0
a=candidate:1780853162 1 udp 1686052607 118.69.35.22 31777 typ srflx raddr 10.10.77.200 rport 43305 generation 0
a=candidate:1780853162 2 udp 1686052606 118.69.35.22 31809 typ srflx raddr 10.10.77.200 rport 37514 generation 0
a=ice-ufrag:jwwczpAehfzwcMgI
a=ice-pwd:fzk6kXPAkSW5ITfMPRXcj64T
a=fingerprint:sha-256 7F:E3:9A:28:1B:30:9B:83:A7:15:D3:ED:A0:34:3C:15:6B:A8:2D:AD:76:0F:AC:AB:10:62:E0:AB:80:5E:78:F2
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:video
a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=extmap:4 urn:3gpp:video-orientation
a=sendrecv
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:100 VP8/90000
a=rtcp-fb:100 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:100 goog-remb
a=rtpmap:116 red/90000
a=rtpmap:117 ulpfec/90000
a=rtpmap:96 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:96 apt=100
a=ssrc-group:FID 940990153 668308246
a=ssrc:940990153 cname:nsTu7lEciv/5dY7Z
a=ssrc:940990153 msid:dchcZgUwyg28FURu8N1orjN1XU09wjZq8k4B dba25e10-fa6a-4e46-8217-924d89802906
a=ssrc:940990153 mslabel:dchcZgUwyg28FURu8N1orjN1XU09wjZq8k4B
a=ssrc:940990153 label:dba25e10-fa6a-4e46-8217-924d89802906
a=ssrc:668308246 cname:nsTu7lEciv/5dY7Z
a=ssrc:668308246 msid:dchcZgUwyg28FURu8N1orjN1XU09wjZq8k4B dba25e10-fa6a-4e46-8217-924d89802906
a=ssrc:668308246 mslabel:dchcZgUwyg28FURu8N1orjN1XU09wjZq8k4B
a=ssrc:668308246 label:dba25e10-fa6a-4e46-8217-924d89802906


sip-0.7.2.js:2892 Wed Nov 04 2015 17:56:27 GMT+0700 (ICT) | sip.transport | received WebSocket text message:

SIP/2.0 100 Trying
Via: SIP/2.0/WSS hvr4pagq2h9f.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK3062994;received=10.10.77.200;rport=38928
From: <sip:1000@10.10.77.168>;tag=mhl4eq6vao
To: <sip:1001@10.10.77.168>
Call-ID: 70fsn4l5nr0fkaouc6fm
CSeq: 5808 INVITE
User-Agent: FreeSWITCH-mod_sofia/1.5.14+git~20141001T233405Z~cc44659a7c~64bit
Content-Length: 0



sip-0.7.2.js:2892 Wed Nov 04 2015 17:56:27 GMT+0700 (ICT) | sip.transport | received WebSocket text message:

SIP/2.0 407 Proxy Authentication Required
Via: SIP/2.0/WSS hvr4pagq2h9f.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK3062994;received=10.10.77.200;rport=38928
From: <sip:1000@10.10.77.168>;tag=mhl4eq6vao
To: <sip:1001@10.10.77.168>;tag=mQ8gp7Ht7yjKg
Call-ID: 70fsn4l5nr0fkaouc6fm
CSeq: 5808 INVITE
User-Agent: FreeSWITCH-mod_sofia/1.5.14+git~20141001T233405Z~cc44659a7c~64bit
Accept: application/sdp
Allow: INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, OPTIONS, MESSAGE, INFO, UPDATE, REGISTER, REFER, NOTIFY, PUBLISH, SUBSCRIBE
Supported: path, replaces
Allow-Events: talk, hold, conference, presence, as-feature-event, dialog, line-seize, call-info, sla, include-session-description, presence.winfo, message-summary, refer
Proxy-Authenticate: Digest realm="10.10.77.168", nonce="045f2c7a-523b-49df-b215-d20064949388", algorithm=MD5, qop="auth"
Content-Length: 0



sip-0.7.2.js:2892 Wed Nov 04 2015 17:56:27 GMT+0700 (ICT) | sip.transport | sending WebSocket message:

ACK sip:1001@10.10.77.168 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/WSS hvr4pagq2h9f.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK3062994
To: <sip:1001@10.10.77.168>;tag=mQ8gp7Ht7yjKg
From: <sip:1000@10.10.77.168>;tag=mhl4eq6vao
Call-ID: 70fsn4l5nr0fkaouc6fm
Content-Length: 0
CSeq: 5808 ACK



sip-0.7.2.js:2892 Wed Nov 04 2015 17:56:27 GMT+0700 (ICT) | sip.transport | sending WebSocket message:

INVITE sip:1001@10.10.77.168 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/WSS hvr4pagq2h9f.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK5985629
Max-Forwards: 70
To: <sip:1001@10.10.77.168>
From: <sip:1000@10.10.77.168>;tag=mhl4eq6vao
Call-ID: 70fsn4l5nr0fkaouc6fm
CSeq: 5809 INVITE
Proxy-Authorization: Digest algorithm=MD5, username="1000", realm="10.10.77.168", nonce="045f2c7a-523b-49df-b215-d20064949388", uri="sip:1001@10.10.77.168", response="767bd2d44925fda232fdcdb05ee4c0a0", qop=auth, cnonce="gv9du6dhptu4", nc=00000001
Contact: <sip:bas2g8qe@hvr4pagq2h9f.invalid;transport=ws;ob>
Allow: ACK,CANCEL,BYE,OPTIONS,INFO,NOTIFY
Content-Type: application/sdp
Supported: outbound
User-Agent: SIP.js/0.7.2
Content-Length: 3631

v=0
o=- 8910623958632335387 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
a=group:BUNDLE audio video
a=msid-semantic: WMS dchcZgUwyg28FURu8N1orjN1XU09wjZq8k4B
m=audio 31713 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 9 0 8 106 105 13 126
c=IN IP4 118.69.35.22
a=rtcp:31745 IN IP4 118.69.35.22
a=candidate:2620772478 1 udp 2122260223 10.10.77.200 52225 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:2620772478 2 udp 2122260222 10.10.77.200 56486 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:3535154318 1 tcp 1518280447 10.10.77.200 0 typ host tcptype active generation 0
a=candidate:3535154318 2 tcp 1518280446 10.10.77.200 0 typ host tcptype active generation 0
a=candidate:1780853162 1 udp 1686052607 118.69.35.22 31713 typ srflx raddr 10.10.77.200 rport 52225 generation 0
a=candidate:1780853162 2 udp 1686052606 118.69.35.22 31745 typ srflx raddr 10.10.77.200 rport 56486 generation 0
a=ice-ufrag:jwwczpAehfzwcMgI
a=ice-pwd:fzk6kXPAkSW5ITfMPRXcj64T
a=fingerprint:sha-256 7F:E3:9A:28:1B:30:9B:83:A7:15:D3:ED:A0:34:3C:15:6B:A8:2D:AD:76:0F:AC:AB:10:62:E0:AB:80:5E:78:F2
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:audio
a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=sendrecv
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
a=fmtp:111 minptime=10; useinbandfec=1
a=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000
a=rtpmap:104 ISAC/32000
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:106 CN/32000
a=rtpmap:105 CN/16000
a=rtpmap:13 CN/8000
a=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000
a=maxptime:60
a=ssrc:4132922782 cname:nsTu7lEciv/5dY7Z
a=ssrc:4132922782 msid:dchcZgUwyg28FURu8N1orjN1XU09wjZq8k4B db705e69-7099-45d5-a3b9-731010988ed4
a=ssrc:4132922782 mslabel:dchcZgUwyg28FURu8N1orjN1XU09wjZq8k4B
a=ssrc:4132922782 label:db705e69-7099-45d5-a3b9-731010988ed4
m=video 31777 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 100 116 117 96
c=IN IP4 118.69.35.22
a=rtcp:31809 IN IP4 118.69.35.22
a=candidate:2620772478 1 udp 2122260223 10.10.77.200 43305 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:2620772478 2 udp 2122260222 10.10.77.200 37514 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:3535154318 1 tcp 1518280447 10.10.77.200 0 typ host tcptype active generation 0
a=candidate:3535154318 2 tcp 1518280446 10.10.77.200 0 typ host tcptype active generation 0
a=candidate:1780853162 1 udp 1686052607 118.69.35.22 31777 typ srflx raddr 10.10.77.200 rport 43305 generation 0
a=candidate:1780853162 2 udp 1686052606 118.69.35.22 31809 typ srflx raddr 10.10.77.200 rport 37514 generation 0
a=ice-ufrag:jwwczpAehfzwcMgI
a=ice-pwd:fzk6kXPAkSW5ITfMPRXcj64T
a=fingerprint:sha-256 7F:E3:9A:28:1B:30:9B:83:A7:15:D3:ED:A0:34:3C:15:6B:A8:2D:AD:76:0F:AC:AB:10:62:E0:AB:80:5E:78:F2
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:video
a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=extmap:4 urn:3gpp:video-orientation
a=sendrecv
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:100 VP8/90000
a=rtcp-fb:100 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:100 goog-remb
a=rtpmap:116 red/90000
a=rtpmap:117 ulpfec/90000
a=rtpmap:96 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:96 apt=100
a=ssrc-group:FID 940990153 668308246
a=ssrc:940990153 cname:nsTu7lEciv/5dY7Z
a=ssrc:940990153 msid:dchcZgUwyg28FURu8N1orjN1XU09wjZq8k4B dba25e10-fa6a-4e46-8217-924d89802906
a=ssrc:940990153 mslabel:dchcZgUwyg28FURu8N1orjN1XU09wjZq8k4B
a=ssrc:940990153 label:dba25e10-fa6a-4e46-8217-924d89802906
a=ssrc:668308246 cname:nsTu7lEciv/5dY7Z
a=ssrc:668308246 msid:dchcZgUwyg28FURu8N1orjN1XU09wjZq8k4B dba25e10-fa6a-4e46-8217-924d89802906
a=ssrc:668308246 mslabel:dchcZgUwyg28FURu8N1orjN1XU09wjZq8k4B
a=ssrc:668308246 label:dba25e10-fa6a-4e46-8217-924d89802906

SIP/2.0 100 Trying
Via: SIP/2.0/WSS hvr4pagq2h9f.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK5985629;received=10.10.77.200;rport=38928
From: <sip:1000@10.10.77.168>;tag=mhl4eq6vao
To: <sip:1001@10.10.77.168>
Call-ID: 70fsn4l5nr0fkaouc6fm
CSeq: 5809 INVITE
User-Agent: FreeSWITCH-mod_sofia/1.5.14+git~20141001T233405Z~cc44659a7c~64bit
Content-Length: 0

SIP/2.0 183 Session Progress
Via: SIP/2.0/WSS hvr4pagq2h9f.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK5985629;received=10.10.77.200;rport=38928
From: <sip:1000@10.10.77.168>;tag=mhl4eq6vao
To: <sip:1001@10.10.77.168>;tag=N019Q22X4785B
Call-ID: 70fsn4l5nr0fkaouc6fm
CSeq: 5809 INVITE
Contact: <sip:1001@10.10.77.168:5060;transport=udp>
User-Agent: FreeSWITCH-mod_sofia/1.5.14+git~20141001T233405Z~cc44659a7c~64bit
Accept: application/sdp
Allow: INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, OPTIONS, MESSAGE, INFO, UPDATE, REGISTER, REFER, NOTIFY, PUBLISH, SUBSCRIBE
Supported: path, replaces
Allow-Events: talk, hold, conference, presence, as-feature-event, dialog, line-seize, call-info, sla, include-session-description, presence.winfo, message-summary, refer
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Disposition: session
Content-Length: 1511
Remote-Party-ID: "1001" <sip:1001@10.10.77.168>;party=calling;privacy=off;screen=no

v=0
o=FreeSWITCH 1446655458 1446655459 IN IP4 10.10.77.168
s=FreeSWITCH
c=IN IP4 10.10.77.168
t=0 0
a=msid-semantic: WMS 3LkKEqje4CiMI55ZI9riOwabytHYaoZ4
m=audio 22304 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 126 106
a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
a=fmtp:111 useinbandfec=1; minptime=10
a=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000
a=rtpmap:106 CN/8000
a=ptime:20
a=fingerprint:sha-256 0B:3C:C0:C3:86:93:01:B5:67:96:9D:72:3A:6D:1F:D5:3E:AA:0A:59:F0:A3:99:6A:F2:DC:FA:16:08:58:F5:55
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp:22304 IN IP4 10.10.77.168
a=ssrc:1044279576 cname:09EuqNzlgIYPDUEc
a=ssrc:1044279576 msid:3LkKEqje4CiMI55ZI9riOwabytHYaoZ4 a0
a=ssrc:1044279576 mslabel:3LkKEqje4CiMI55ZI9riOwabytHYaoZ4
a=ssrc:1044279576 label:3LkKEqje4CiMI55ZI9riOwabytHYaoZ4a0
a=ice-ufrag:TVkyilAGE7vFmlzd
a=ice-pwd:l4xBHXNOvBtZmX26JduRpUoT
a=candidate:8329015189 1 udp 659136 10.10.77.168 22304 typ host generation 0
m=video 24884 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 100
b=AS:256
a=rtpmap:100 VP8/90000
a=fingerprint:sha-256 0B:3C:C0:C3:86:93:01:B5:67:96:9D:72:3A:6D:1F:D5:3E:AA:0A:59:F0:A3:99:6A:F2:DC:FA:16:08:58:F5:55
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp:24884 IN IP4 10.10.77.168
a=rtcp-fb:* fir 
a=rtcp-fb:100 ccm fir
a=ssrc:320961444 cname:09EuqNzlgIYPDUEc
a=ssrc:320961444 msid:3LkKEqje4CiMI55ZI9riOwabytHYaoZ4 v0
a=ssrc:320961444 mslabel:3LkKEqje4CiMI55ZI9riOwabytHYaoZ4
a=ssrc:320961444 label:3LkKEqje4CiMI55ZI9riOwabytHYaoZ4v0
a=ice-ufrag:tlnOULrNP50AYEdz
a=ice-pwd:C8vrUfeU3NbQAkOTw1xgCPUi
a=candidate:9305711577 1 udp 659136 10.10.77.168 24884 typ host generation 0

INFO sip:bas2g8qe@hvr4pagq2h9f.invalid;transport=ws;ob SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/WSS 10.10.77.168:7443;branch=z9hG4bKBr48atcSXjt2e
Max-Forwards: 70
From: <sip:1001@10.10.77.168>;tag=N019Q22X4785B
To: <sip:1000@10.10.77.168>;tag=mhl4eq6vao
Call-ID: 70fsn4l5nr0fkaouc6fm
CSeq: 83002817 INFO
Contact: <sip:1001@10.10.77.168:5060;transport=udp>
User-Agent: FreeSWITCH-mod_sofia/1.5.14+git~20141001T233405Z~cc44659a7c~64bit
Allow: INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, OPTIONS, MESSAGE, INFO, UPDATE, REGISTER, REFER, NOTIFY, PUBLISH, SUBSCRIBE
Supported: path, replaces
Content-Type: application/media_control+xml
Content-Length: 175

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<media_control>
<vc_primitive>
<to_encoder>
<picture_fast_update>
</picture_fast_update>
</to_encoder>
</vc_primitive>
</media_control>

SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/WSS hvr4pagq2h9f.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK5985629;received=10.10.77.200;rport=38928
From: <sip:1000@10.10.77.168>;tag=mhl4eq6vao
To: <sip:1001@10.10.77.168>;tag=N019Q22X4785B
Call-ID: 70fsn4l5nr0fkaouc6fm
CSeq: 5809 INVITE
Contact: <sip:1001@10.10.77.168:5060;transport=udp>
User-Agent: FreeSWITCH-mod_sofia/1.5.14+git~20141001T233405Z~cc44659a7c~64bit
Allow: INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, OPTIONS, MESSAGE, INFO, UPDATE, REGISTER, REFER, NOTIFY, PUBLISH, SUBSCRIBE
Supported: path, replaces
Allow-Events: talk, hold, conference, presence, as-feature-event, dialog, line-seize, call-info, sla, include-session-description, presence.winfo, message-summary, refer
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Disposition: session
Content-Length: 1511
Remote-Party-ID: "Outbound Call" <sip:qr454isu@10.10.77.168>;party=calling;privacy=off;screen=no

v=0
o=FreeSWITCH 1446655458 1446655459 IN IP4 10.10.77.168
s=FreeSWITCH
c=IN IP4 10.10.77.168
t=0 0
a=msid-semantic: WMS 3LkKEqje4CiMI55ZI9riOwabytHYaoZ4
m=audio 22304 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 126 106
a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
a=fmtp:111 useinbandfec=1; minptime=10
a=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000
a=rtpmap:106 CN/8000
a=ptime:20
a=fingerprint:sha-256 0B:3C:C0:C3:86:93:01:B5:67:96:9D:72:3A:6D:1F:D5:3E:AA:0A:59:F0:A3:99:6A:F2:DC:FA:16:08:58:F5:55
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp:22304 IN IP4 10.10.77.168
a=ssrc:1044279576 cname:09EuqNzlgIYPDUEc
a=ssrc:1044279576 msid:3LkKEqje4CiMI55ZI9riOwabytHYaoZ4 a0
a=ssrc:1044279576 mslabel:3LkKEqje4CiMI55ZI9riOwabytHYaoZ4
a=ssrc:1044279576 label:3LkKEqje4CiMI55ZI9riOwabytHYaoZ4a0
a=ice-ufrag:TVkyilAGE7vFmlzd
a=ice-pwd:l4xBHXNOvBtZmX26JduRpUoT
a=candidate:8329015189 1 udp 659136 10.10.77.168 22304 typ host generation 0
m=video 24884 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 100
b=AS:256
a=rtpmap:100 VP8/90000
a=fingerprint:sha-256 0B:3C:C0:C3:86:93:01:B5:67:96:9D:72:3A:6D:1F:D5:3E:AA:0A:59:F0:A3:99:6A:F2:DC:FA:16:08:58:F5:55
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp:24884 IN IP4 10.10.77.168
a=rtcp-fb:* fir 
a=rtcp-fb:100 ccm fir
a=ssrc:320961444 cname:09EuqNzlgIYPDUEc
a=ssrc:320961444 msid:3LkKEqje4CiMI55ZI9riOwabytHYaoZ4 v0
a=ssrc:320961444 mslabel:3LkKEqje4CiMI55ZI9riOwabytHYaoZ4
a=ssrc:320961444 label:3LkKEqje4CiMI55ZI9riOwabytHYaoZ4v0
a=ice-ufrag:tlnOULrNP50AYEdz
a=ice-pwd:C8vrUfeU3NbQAkOTw1xgCPUi
a=candidate:9305711577 1 udp 659136 10.10.77.168 24884 typ host generation 0


sip-0.7.2.js:2892 Wed Nov 04 2015 17:56:37 GMT+0700 (ICT) | sip.dialog | dialog 70fsn4l5nr0fkaouc6fmmhl4eq6vaoN019Q22X4785B  changed to CONFIRMED state
sip-0.7.2.js:2892 Wed Nov 04 2015 17:56:38 GMT+0700 (ICT) | sip.transport | sending WebSocket message:

ACK sip:1001@10.10.77.168:5060;transport=udp SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/WSS hvr4pagq2h9f.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK161604
Max-Forwards: 70
To: <sip:1001@10.10.77.168>;tag=N019Q22X4785B
From: <sip:1000@10.10.77.168>;tag=mhl4eq6vao
Call-ID: 70fsn4l5nr0fkaouc6fm
CSeq: 5809 ACK
Supported: outbound
User-Agent: SIP.js/0.7.2
Content-Length: 0
```

Log from callee

```
Wed Nov 04 2015 17:56:37 GMT+0700 (ICT) | sip.transport | received WebSocket text message:

INVITE sip:qr454isu@nu5qvarjk5d8.invalid;transport=ws SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/WSS 10.10.77.168:7443;branch=z9hG4bKaFBg9yUN093FK
Route: <sip:qr454isu@10.10.77.200:38933>;transport=wss
Max-Forwards: 69
From: "Extension 1000" <sip:1000@10.10.77.168>;tag=p9t2SXK11gZrQ
To: <sip:qr454isu@nu5qvarjk5d8.invalid;transport=ws>
Call-ID: 1051aa3b-fdea-1233-63a6-b888e3ea758c
CSeq: 83002817 INVITE
Contact: <sip:mod_sofia@10.10.77.168:5060>
User-Agent: FreeSWITCH-mod_sofia/1.5.14+git~20141001T233405Z~cc44659a7c~64bit
Allow: INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, OPTIONS, MESSAGE, INFO, UPDATE, REGISTER, REFER, NOTIFY, PUBLISH, SUBSCRIBE
Supported: path, replaces
Allow-Events: talk, hold, conference, presence, as-feature-event, dialog, line-seize, call-info, sla, include-session-description, presence.winfo, message-summary, refer
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Disposition: session
Content-Length: 1686
X-FS-Support: update_display,send_info
Remote-Party-ID: "Extension 1000" <sip:1000@10.10.77.168>;party=calling;screen=yes;privacy=off

v=0
o=FreeSWITCH 1446655028 1446655029 IN IP4 10.10.77.168
s=FreeSWITCH
c=IN IP4 10.10.77.168
t=0 0
a=msid-semantic: WMS rTofDhzmsraJoVtOLeKe5Oq9ZqEtMsE3
m=audio 22734 RTP/SAVPF 111 9 0 8 101 13
a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
a=fmtp:111 minptime=10; useinbandfec=1
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=fingerprint:sha-256 0B:3C:C0:C3:86:93:01:B5:67:96:9D:72:3A:6D:1F:D5:3E:AA:0A:59:F0:A3:99:6A:F2:DC:FA:16:08:58:F5:55
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp:22734 IN IP4 10.10.77.168
a=ssrc:3929967458 cname:cT9F0ySjPTS3EcIg
a=ssrc:3929967458 msid:rTofDhzmsraJoVtOLeKe5Oq9ZqEtMsE3 a0
a=ssrc:3929967458 mslabel:rTofDhzmsraJoVtOLeKe5Oq9ZqEtMsE3
a=ssrc:3929967458 label:rTofDhzmsraJoVtOLeKe5Oq9ZqEtMsE3a0
a=ice-ufrag:gjlcXBbNRF7uYBn0
a=ice-pwd:knwbMekrX3ls5Uyc3JeRbfuS
a=candidate:9160349578 1 udp 659136 10.10.77.168 22734 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:9160349578 2 udp 659136 10.10.77.168 22734 typ host generation 0
a=ptime:20
m=video 19078 RTP/SAVPF 100
b=AS:256
a=rtpmap:100 VP8/90000
a=fingerprint:sha-256 0B:3C:C0:C3:86:93:01:B5:67:96:9D:72:3A:6D:1F:D5:3E:AA:0A:59:F0:A3:99:6A:F2:DC:FA:16:08:58:F5:55
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp:19078 IN IP4 10.10.77.168
a=rtcp-fb:100 ccm fir
a=ssrc:3206649321 cname:cT9F0ySjPTS3EcIg
a=ssrc:3206649321 msid:rTofDhzmsraJoVtOLeKe5Oq9ZqEtMsE3 v0
a=ssrc:3206649321 mslabel:rTofDhzmsraJoVtOLeKe5Oq9ZqEtMsE3
a=ssrc:3206649321 label:rTofDhzmsraJoVtOLeKe5Oq9ZqEtMsE3v0
a=ice-ufrag:TRBBEdlBbRgZcZdt
a=ice-pwd:zImgW4DCi2PzuqHe79FBcQ3e
a=candidate:3388707440 1 udp 659136 10.10.77.168 19078 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:3388707440 2 udp 659134 10.10.77.168 19078 typ host generation 0

SIP/2.0 100 Trying
Via: SIP/2.0/WSS 10.10.77.168:7443;branch=z9hG4bKaFBg9yUN093FK
To: <sip:qr454isu@nu5qvarjk5d8.invalid;transport=ws>
From: "Extension 1000" <sip:1000@10.10.77.168>;tag=p9t2SXK11gZrQ
Call-ID: 1051aa3b-fdea-1233-63a6-b888e3ea758c
CSeq: 83002817 INVITE
Supported: outbound
User-Agent: SIP.js/0.7.2
Content-Length: 0



sip-0.7.2.js:2892 Wed Nov 04 2015 17:56:37 GMT+0700 (ICT) | sip.dialog | new UAS dialog created with status EARLY
sip-0.7.2.js:2892 Wed Nov 04 2015 17:56:37 GMT+0700 (ICT) | sip.transport | sending WebSocket message:

SIP/2.0 180 Ringing
Via: SIP/2.0/WSS 10.10.77.168:7443;branch=z9hG4bKaFBg9yUN093FK
To: <sip:qr454isu@nu5qvarjk5d8.invalid;transport=ws>;tag=rtfa22915i
From: "Extension 1000" <sip:1000@10.10.77.168>;tag=p9t2SXK11gZrQ
Call-ID: 1051aa3b-fdea-1233-63a6-b888e3ea758c
CSeq: 83002817 INVITE
Contact: <sip:qr454isu@nu5qvarjk5d8.invalid;transport=ws>
Supported: outbound
User-Agent: SIP.js/0.7.2
Content-Length: 0



sip-0.7.2.js:2892 Wed Nov 04 2015 17:56:37 GMT+0700 (ICT) | sip.dialog | dialog 1051aa3b-fdea-1233-63a6-b888e3ea758crtfa22915ip9t2SXK11gZrQ  changed to CONFIRMED state
sip-0.7.2.js:2892 Wed Nov 04 2015 17:56:37 GMT+0700 (ICT) | sip.invitecontext.mediahandler | acquiring local media
sip-0.7.2.js:2892 Wed Nov 04 2015 17:56:37 GMT+0700 (ICT) | sip.invitecontext.mediahandler | stream added: rTofDhzmsraJoVtOLeKe5Oq9ZqEtMsE3
sip-0.7.2.js:2892 Wed Nov 04 2015 17:56:37 GMT+0700 (ICT) | sip.invitecontext.mediahandler | acquired local media streams
sip-0.7.2.js:2892 Wed Nov 04 2015 17:56:37 GMT+0700 (ICT) | sip.invitecontext.mediahandler | ICE candidate received: candidate:2620772478 1 udp 2122260223 10.10.77.200 36793 typ host generation 0
sip-0.7.2.js:2892 Wed Nov 04 2015 17:56:37 GMT+0700 (ICT) | sip.invitecontext.mediahandler | ICE candidate received: candidate:2620772478 1 udp 2122260223 10.10.77.200 47940 typ host generation 0
2sip-0.7.2.js:2892 Wed Nov 04 2015 17:56:37 GMT+0700 (ICT) | sip.invitecontext.mediahandler | ICE candidate received: candidate:3535154318 1 tcp 1518280447 10.10.77.200 0 typ host tcptype active generation 0
sip-0.7.2.js:2892 Wed Nov 04 2015 17:56:37 GMT+0700 (ICT) | sip.invitecontext.mediahandler | ICE candidate received: candidate:1780853162 1 udp 1686052607 118.69.35.22 32929 typ srflx raddr 10.10.77.200 rport 36793 generation 0
sip-0.7.2.js:2892 Wed Nov 04 2015 17:56:37 GMT+0700 (ICT) | sip.invitecontext.mediahandler | ICE candidate received: candidate:1780853162 1 udp 1686052607 118.69.35.22 32961 typ srflx raddr 10.10.77.200 rport 47940 generation 0
sip-0.7.2.js:2892 Wed Nov 04 2015 17:56:37 GMT+0700 (ICT) | sip.transport | sending WebSocket message:

SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/WSS 10.10.77.168:7443;branch=z9hG4bKaFBg9yUN093FK
To: <sip:qr454isu@nu5qvarjk5d8.invalid;transport=ws>;tag=rtfa22915i
From: "Extension 1000" <sip:1000@10.10.77.168>;tag=p9t2SXK11gZrQ
Call-ID: 1051aa3b-fdea-1233-63a6-b888e3ea758c
CSeq: 83002817 INVITE
Contact: <sip:qr454isu@nu5qvarjk5d8.invalid;transport=ws>
Allow: ACK,CANCEL,BYE,OPTIONS,INFO,NOTIFY,INVITE
Supported: outbound
User-Agent: SIP.js/0.7.2
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 2147

v=0
o=- 450693245228317432 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
a=msid-semantic: WMS qtxpjUNxJGxVKp1WBxjDpxXl1GgPcFXBV68H
m=audio 32929 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 9 0 8 101 13
c=IN IP4 118.69.35.22
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 192.0.2.117
a=candidate:2620772478 1 udp 2122260223 10.10.77.200 36793 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:3535154318 1 tcp 1518280447 10.10.77.200 0 typ host tcptype active generation 0
a=candidate:1780853162 1 udp 1686052607 118.69.35.22 32929 typ srflx raddr 10.10.77.200 rport 36793 generation 0
a=ice-ufrag:vReUafh5N/1vCMfe
a=ice-pwd:6QLlj3LHe8yLUVP4GEGQoOnC
a=fingerprint:sha-256 EF:EA:6A:5F:BA:43:AD:8B:7A:0F:29:F2:35:3C:D7:36:A4:1D:2C:64:75:46:22:45:FA:A8:17:AB:B4:92:D8:09
a=setup:active
a=mid:audio
a=sendrecv
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
a=fmtp:111 minptime=10; useinbandfec=1
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=rtpmap:13 CN/8000
a=maxptime:60
a=ssrc:2661729315 cname:bksnJlwwUfKnLBx2
a=ssrc:2661729315 msid:qtxpjUNxJGxVKp1WBxjDpxXl1GgPcFXBV68H d6c81e88-c7ee-4cd8-9be2-7e9e2f6fd148
a=ssrc:2661729315 mslabel:qtxpjUNxJGxVKp1WBxjDpxXl1GgPcFXBV68H
a=ssrc:2661729315 label:d6c81e88-c7ee-4cd8-9be2-7e9e2f6fd148
m=video 32961 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 100
c=IN IP4 118.69.35.22
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 192.0.2.117
a=candidate:2620772478 1 udp 2122260223 10.10.77.200 47940 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:3535154318 1 tcp 1518280447 10.10.77.200 0 typ host tcptype active generation 0
a=candidate:1780853162 1 udp 1686052607 118.69.35.22 32961 typ srflx raddr 10.10.77.200 rport 47940 generation 0
a=ice-ufrag:ci9ak8CI008FYNGt
a=ice-pwd:1Y+h/BDZZgr+ro/hfXKMiJhn
a=fingerprint:sha-256 EF:EA:6A:5F:BA:43:AD:8B:7A:0F:29:F2:35:3C:D7:36:A4:1D:2C:64:75:46:22:45:FA:A8:17:AB:B4:92:D8:09
a=setup:active
a=mid:video
a=sendrecv
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:100 VP8/90000
a=rtcp-fb:100 ccm fir
a=ssrc:1847688147 cname:bksnJlwwUfKnLBx2
a=ssrc:1847688147 msid:qtxpjUNxJGxVKp1WBxjDpxXl1GgPcFXBV68H 00560cf1-1fd6-419c-8487-6a597d360646
a=ssrc:1847688147 mslabel:qtxpjUNxJGxVKp1WBxjDpxXl1GgPcFXBV68H
a=ssrc:1847688147 label:00560cf1-1fd6-419c-8487-6a597d360646


sip-0.7.2.js:2892 Wed Nov 04 2015 17:56:37 GMT+0700 (ICT) | sip.transport | received WebSocket text message:

ACK sip:qr454isu@nu5qvarjk5d8.invalid;transport=ws SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/WSS 10.10.77.168:7443;branch=z9hG4bKc1X1cNXvtUgNa
Max-Forwards: 70
From: "Extension 1000" <sip:1000@10.10.77.168>;tag=p9t2SXK11gZrQ
To: <sip:qr454isu@nu5qvarjk5d8.invalid;transport=ws>;tag=rtfa22915i
Call-ID: 1051aa3b-fdea-1233-63a6-b888e3ea758c
CSeq: 83002817 ACK
Contact: <sip:mod_sofia@10.10.77.168:5060>
Content-Length: 0



sip-0.7.2.js:2892 Wed Nov 04 2015 17:56:37 GMT+0700 (ICT) | sip.transport | received WebSocket text message:

INFO sip:qr454isu@nu5qvarjk5d8.invalid;transport=ws SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/WSS 10.10.77.168:7443;branch=z9hG4bKDaQtege0Q467N
Max-Forwards: 70
From: "Extension 1000" <sip:1000@10.10.77.168>;tag=p9t2SXK11gZrQ
To: <sip:qr454isu@nu5qvarjk5d8.invalid;transport=ws>;tag=rtfa22915i
Call-ID: 1051aa3b-fdea-1233-63a6-b888e3ea758c
CSeq: 83002818 INFO
Contact: <sip:mod_sofia@10.10.77.168:5060>
User-Agent: FreeSWITCH-mod_sofia/1.5.14+git~20141001T233405Z~cc44659a7c~64bit
Allow: INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, OPTIONS, MESSAGE, INFO, UPDATE, REGISTER, REFER, NOTIFY, PUBLISH, SUBSCRIBE
Supported: path, replaces
Content-Type: application/media_control+xml
Content-Length: 175

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<media_control>
<vc_primitive>
<to_encoder>
<picture_fast_update>
</picture_fast_update>
</to_encoder>
</vc_primitive>
</media_control>

sip-0.7.2.js:2892 Wed Nov 04 2015 17:56:38 GMT+0700 (ICT) | sip.transport | sending WebSocket message:

SIP/2.0 415 Unsupported Media Type
Via: SIP/2.0/WSS 10.10.77.168:7443;branch=z9hG4bKDaQtege0Q467N
To: <sip:qr454isu@nu5qvarjk5d8.invalid;transport=ws>;tag=rtfa22915i
From: "Extension 1000" <sip:1000@10.10.77.168>;tag=p9t2SXK11gZrQ
Call-ID: 1051aa3b-fdea-1233-63a6-b888e3ea758c
CSeq: 83002818 INFO
Accept: application/dtmf-relay
Supported: outbound
User-Agent: SIP.js/0.7.2
Content-Length: 0
```

I was tried a lot of WebRTC client tools but just a same problem so I guess it happening from FreeSwitch server.

Anyone please help me, very high appreciate.

Answer (score 2):

From your caller and callee log.

caller

```
Contact: <sip:bas2g8qe@hvr4pagq2h9f.invalid;transport=ws;ob>
```

callee

```
To: <sip:qr454isu@nu5qvarjk5d8.invalid;transport=ws>;tag=rtfa22915i
```

It seems they both are connect with pure WebSocket without SSL. Try to connect via wss, it works in my test environment.

Secure connection is a requirement, not an option.

Comment: Thanks @Orson, I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

This purely seems like NAT issues to me from a=rtcp:xxxx IN IP4 10.10.77.168

Please try this:

1. Try using `<action application="set" data="bypass_media=true"/>`
    before bridge application. "No media handling mode"
   this will rule out audio dependencies from freeswitch. Once this change reloadxml and make call again to see if audio works. If it does, then there is no issues with client side.(STUN works good.)
2. Now remove bypass_media from dial plan and set

   `<param name="ext-rtp-ip" value="auto-nat"/>
   <param name="ext-sip-ip" value="auto-nat"/>`

   in your sip profile, may be internal.xml
3. If 2. doesn't work. Try adding the external ip address manually by replacing `auto-nat`.

I hope this helps!

Comment: After changing STUN server, it was working. @Sasi thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

setting "bypass_media=true" in dial-plan before bridge  solved no rtp problem in my freeswitch verto configuration. I was trying extension to extension calling with custom verto profile.